# Unable to get a prediction result in shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, random-forest, prediction, shinydashboard

I am trying to build a Shiny app that predicts hotel cancellations. But when I click on the action button the user does not get a prediction. Can you please help me to solve this problem? I am new to Shiny app and coding in R.

The dataset can be found at this link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AnJKSfuVbEqDgQKHaSPuNHhVfkNk?e=pNNulI

````
hotel <- read.csv("/Users/sabrinagreifzu/Documents/Masterstudium Data Science/Anwedungsentwicklung/Stackoverflow/Hotel_Prediction_SG_1.csv", head = TRUE, sep=",")

hotel$is_canceled <- as.factor(hotel$is_canceled)
hotel$is_repeated_guest <- as.factor(hotel$is_repeated_guest)
hotel$meal <- as.factor(hotel$meal)
hotel$reserved_room_type <- as.factor(hotel$reserved_room_type)
hotel$deposit_type <- as.factor(hotel$deposit_type)
hotel$customer_type <- as.factor(hotel$customer_type)
hotel$adr <- as.integer(hotel$adr)
hotel$hotel <- as.factor(hotel$hotel)


#Cross Validation
install.packages("rsample")
library(rsample)
data <- initial_split(hotel, .75, is_canceled)

train <- training(data)
test <- testing(data)

#X-y Splitting
train_x <- select(train, -is_canceled)
test_x <- select(test, -is_canceled)
train_y <- train$is_canceled
test_y <- test$is_canceled

#Machine Learning Modelling
set.seed(42)
model_rf <- randomForest(train_x, train_y, ntree = 100)

confusionMatrix(predict(model_rf, test_x), test_y)


#Saving the model
saveRDS(model_rf, file = "./model_rf.rda")


ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(title = "Hotel Prediction",
                                    titleWidth = 290),
                    dashboardSidebar(width = 290,
                                     sidebarMenu(menuItem("Prediction", tabName = 'pred'))),
                    dashboardBody(
                      tabItems(
                        tabItem('pred',
                                #Filters for categorical variables
                                box(title = 'Categorical variables', 
                                    status = 'primary', width = 12, 
                                    splitLayout(
                                      tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".shiny-split-layout > div {overflow: visible;}"))),
                                      cellWidths = c('0%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '8%'),
                                      selectInput('deposit_type', 'Bezahltyp', c("No Deposit", "Non Refund","Refundable")),
                                      div(),
                                      selectInput('customer_type','Kundentyp', c('Transient','Contract','Group','Transient-Party')))),
                                
                              
                                #Box to display the prediction results
                                box(title = 'Prediction result',
                                    status = 'success', 
                                    solidHeader = TRUE, 
                                    width = 12, height = 260,
                                    div(h5('Total number of cancellations:')),
                                    textOutput('predicted_value'),
                                    actionButton('cal', 'Calculate', icon = icon('calculator'))),
                                
                                
                        )
                      )
                    ))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  
  observeEvent(input$cal,{
    data <- data.frame(
      Bezahltyp = input$deposit_type,
      Kundentyp = input$customer_type)
      
      output$predicted_value <- renderText({
        predict(model_rf,data())
      })
  })
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)```
````

Comment: Please try to make a _minimal_ reproducible example.  Your question is about an action button not causing a calculation.  But you include an enormous amount of irrelevant code, like `str(hotel)` and `nrow(hotel)`.

Comment: Hi Michael, thanks for your answer. I have shortened the code a bit and hope that it is now a bit more understandable.

Comment: Your code still does not run.  For example, I do not know what package `randomForest` comes from.  It is not clear if your asking about how to get Shiny to do what you want, or if you want your model to run properly.  Which are you having trouble with?

Comment: Your `observeEvent`  is wrong because it should not have the `renderText` inside of it.  But since I don't know what you want, it's hard to suggest how to change it.

Answer (score 0):

To me, there seems to be several reasons why you don't get a prediction:

#### 1. Misspecification of the predict data

We see that the model is trained on 13 variables

```r
> train_x %>% names()
 [1] "hotel"                          "adults"                        
 [3] "children"                       "babies"                        
 [5] "meal"                           "is_repeated_guest"             
 [7] "previous_cancellations"         "previous_bookings_not_canceled"
 [9] "reserved_room_type"             "deposit_type"                  
[11] "customer_type"                  "adr"                           
[13] "total_of_special_requests"
```

But when you try to `predict(model_rf, data())` your dataset is only containing two variables:

```r
data.frame(
    Bezahltyp = input$deposit_type,
    Kundentyp = input$customer_type
)
```

and the variables don't even have the same names as in the training data. How will the model know which variables and values to use for the prediction?

This would give you an error like `variables in the training data missing in newdata` even when run outside of Shiny.

Fix this by supplying a dataframe with all variables the model was trained on to the predict function.

#### 2. Shiny error

In your current example, you do `predict(model_rf, data())` but `data` is not a reactive value, so R thinks you mean the function `utils::data()`. This leads to the error `number of variables in newdata does not match that in the training data`.

I believe that in your first example, data was wrapped in `reactive({})` but that the closing `})` was misplaced. It needs to be closed before calling the `predict()` function.

Here is an example of a good server side structure for this application:

```r
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
    
    data <- reactive({
        
        # Create your dataset here
        # It needs to have the same variables as train_x
        
    })
    
    output$predicted_value <- renderText({
        
        predict(model_rf, data())
        
    }) %>% 
        # bindEvent is recommended over eventReactive
        bindEvent(input$cal)
    
})
```

### Working example

Under I have created a smaller working example of your app (btw, for your next question, you want to provide this from the start). I have removed anything I deemed unnecessary for this illustration. I have changed the structure of the server, so that it actually returns predictions. I think you should be able to reuse this structure for your project.

```r
hotel <- structure(
    list(
        hotel = c(
            "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
            "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
            "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
            "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
            "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
            "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
            "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
            "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
            "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
            "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
            "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
            "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
            "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel"), 
        is_canceled = c(0, 
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                        0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                        0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
        adults = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
                   2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
                   2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
        children = c(0, 
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                     0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                     0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
        babies = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                   0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
        meal = c("BB", 
                 "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "FB", "BB", "HB", "BB", "HB", 
                 "BB", "HB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", 
                 "BB", "HB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", 
                 "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "HB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "HB", "BB", 
                 "BB", "BB", "BB", "HB", "HB"), 
        is_repeated_guest = c(
            0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0
        ), 
        previous_cancellations = c(
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0
        ), 
        previous_bookings_not_canceled = c(
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
            0
        ), 
        reserved_room_type = c(
            "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", 
            "C", "A", "D", "E", "D", "D", "G", "E", "D", "E", "A", "A", "G", 
            "F", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "A", "D", "A", "D", "E", 
            "A", "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "E", "G", "D", "F", "E", "A", "G", 
            "A", "E", "A", "E"
        ), 
        deposit_type = c(
            "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
            "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
            "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
            "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
            "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
            "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
            "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
            "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
            "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
            "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
            "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit"
        ), 
        customer_type = c(
            "Transient", 
            "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
            "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
            "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
            "Contract", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
            "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Contract", "Transient", 
            "Contract", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
            "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
            "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
            "Contract", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
            "Transient", "Transient-Party", "Contract", "Transient"
        ), 
        adr = c(
            0, 
            0, 75, 75, 98, 98, 107, 103, 82, 105, 123, 145, 97, 154, 94, 
            97, 97, 88, 107, 153, 97, 84, 84, 99, 94, 63, 79, 107, 94, 87, 
            62, 63, 108, 65, 108, 108, 98, 108, 108, 137, 117, 79, 123, 137, 
            110, 153, 58, 82, 82, 119
        ), 
        total_of_special_requests = c(
            0, 
            0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
            1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
            1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1
        )
    ), 
    row.names = c(NA, -50L), 
    class = c("tbl_df", 
              "tbl", "data.frame")
)

hotel$is_canceled <- as.factor(hotel$is_canceled)
hotel$is_repeated_guest <- as.factor(hotel$is_repeated_guest)
hotel$meal <- as.factor(hotel$meal)
hotel$reserved_room_type <- as.factor(hotel$reserved_room_type)
hotel$deposit_type <- as.factor(hotel$deposit_type)
hotel$customer_type <- as.factor(hotel$customer_type)
hotel$adr <- as.integer(hotel$adr)
hotel$hotel <- as.factor(hotel$hotel)

library(dplyr)

train_x <- select(hotel, -is_canceled)
train_y <- hotel$is_canceled

set.seed(42)
# I'm assuming you are using the randomForest package
model_rf <- randomForest::randomForest(train_x, train_y, ntree = 100)


library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(
        title = "Hotel Prediction",
        titleWidth = 290
    ),
    dashboardSidebar(
        width = 290,
        sidebarMenu(menuItem("Prediction", tabName = 'pred'))),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(
                'pred',
                # Box to display the prediction results
                box(
                    title = 'Prediction result',
                    width = 12, 
                    height = 260,
                    textOutput('predicted_value'),
                    actionButton('cal', 'Calculate', icon = icon('calculator'))
                )
            )
        )
    )
)


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
    
    data <- reactive({
        
        # Create your dataset here
        train_x
        
    })
    
    output$predicted_value <- renderText({
        
        predict(model_rf, data())
        
    }) %>% 
        # bindEvent is recommended over eventReactive
        bindEvent(input$cal)
    
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for sharing a solution example. However, I would like to output the prediction accuracy to the user. I.e. if a user selects e.g. Adults = 4, is repeated guest = 1, previous cancellations = 1, reserved room type = B, then the user should be shown in percent how likely it is that the booking will be cancelled. I hope you understand what I mean?

Comment: If you add the argument `type = "prob"`  to the `predict()` function you will get this. This is quite standard for predict in R, but you can see all specific documentation for predicting a `randomForest` model with `?randomForest:::predict.randomForest()`. Note that the output from `type = "prob"` is a matrix, containing both the probability of the booking being cancelled, and the probability it's not being cancelled (summing to 1). So you will need to do some data handling in the server to return only the number you are looking for.

Comment: Nevertheless, Shiny gives me the following error: Error: In sliderInput(): `min`, `max`, and `value` cannot be NULL, NA, or empty.

I have checked via the following function (length(which(rowSums(is.na(hotel))>0)) )to check if there are NULL, NA, or empty values in the dataset, but there are not. Could you help me one more time and tell me if the input slider elements are included correctly in the server?

Comment: That error message means that you have created a `sliderInput()` without specifying the argument `min`, `max` and/or `value`. Try changing your `sliderInput`s for `is_repeated_guest` and `meal` to `selectInput()`  instead. `sliderInput()` is for numeric input only.

Answer (score 0):

This is the current code:

````
  list(
    hotel = c(
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "City Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "City Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "City Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "City Hotel"), 
    is_canceled = c(0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    adults = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
               2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
    children = c(0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    babies = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    meal = c("BB", 
             "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "FB", "BB", "HB", "BB", "HB", 
             "BB", "HB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "SC", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", 
             "BB", "HB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "SC", "BB", "BB", "BB", 
             "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "HB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "Undefined", "Undefined", 
             "BB", "FB", "BB", "FB", "HB"), 
    is_repeated_guest = c(
      0, 0, 0, 
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 1
    ), 
    previous_cancellations = c(
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0
    ), 
    previous_bookings_not_canceled = c(
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0
    ), 
    reserved_room_type = c(
      "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", 
      "C", "A", "D", "E", "D", "D", "G", "E", "D", "E", "A", "A", "G", 
      "F", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "A", "D", "A", "D", "E", 
      "A", "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "E", "G", "D", "F", "E", "A", "G", 
      "A", "E", "A", "E"
    ), 
    deposit_type = c(
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "Refundable", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "Non Refund", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "Non Refund", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "Refundable", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "Non Refund", "No Deposit", "Non Refund", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "Refundable", "No Deposit", "No Deposit"
    ), 
    customer_type = c(
      "Transient", 
      "Group", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Group", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Contract", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient", "Transient-Party", "Contract", "Transient", 
      "Contract", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Contract", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient-Party", "Contract", "Transient"
    ), 
    adr = c(
      0, 
      0, 75, 75, 98, 98, 107, 103, 82, 105, 123, 145, 97, 154, 94, 
      97, 97, 88, 107, 153, 97, 84, 84, 99, 94, 63, 79, 107, 94, 87, 
      62, 63, 108, 65, 108, 108, 98, 108, 108, 137, 117, 79, 123, 137, 
      110, 153, 58, 82, 82, 119
    ), 
    total_of_special_requests = c(
      0, 
      0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
      1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
      1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1
    )
  ), 
  row.names = c(NA, -50L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", 
            "tbl", "data.frame")
)

hotel$is_canceled <- as.factor(hotel$is_canceled)
hotel$is_repeated_guest <- as.factor(hotel$is_repeated_guest)
hotel$meal <- as.factor(hotel$meal)
hotel$reserved_room_type <- as.factor(hotel$reserved_room_type)
hotel$deposit_type <- as.factor(hotel$deposit_type)
hotel$customer_type <- as.factor(hotel$customer_type)
hotel$adr <- as.integer(hotel$adr)
hotel$hotel <- as.factor(hotel$hotel)

library(dplyr)

train_x <- select(hotel, -is_canceled)
train_y <- hotel$is_canceled

set.seed(42)
model_rf <- randomForest::randomForest(train_x, train_y, ntree = 100)


str(train_x)
hotel <- select(hotel, -is_canceled)


library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Hotel Prediction",
    titleWidth = 290
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 290,
    sidebarMenu(menuItem("Prediction", tabName = 'pred'))),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        'pred',
        # Box to display the prediction results
        
        box(
            status = 'primary', width = 12, 
            splitLayout(
              tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".shiny-split-layout > div {overflow: visible;}"))),
              cellWidths = c('0%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '8%'),
              selectInput('hotel', 'hotel', c('City Hotel','Resort Hotel')),
              div(),
              sliderInput('adults', 'Erwachsene', min = 0, max = 26, value = 0),
              div(),
              sliderInput('children', 'Kinder', min = 0, max = 3, value = 0))),
        
        
        #Filters for numeric variables
        box(
            status = 'primary', width = 12,
            splitLayout(
              cellWidths = c('22%', '4%','21%', '4%', '21%', '4%', '21%'),
              sliderInput('babies', 'Babys', min = 0, max = 10, value = 0),
              div(),
              selectInput('meal', 'Mahlzeit', c('BB','HB','SC','Undefined','FB')),
              div(),
              selectInput('is_repeated_guest', 'Wiederholter Gast',  c('1','0')),
              div(),
              sliderInput('previous_cancellations', 'Stornierungen', min = 0, max = 26, value = 0))),
        
        box(
            status = 'primary', width = 12,
            splitLayout(
              cellWidths = c('22%', '4%','21%', '4%', '21%', '4%', '21%'),
              selectInput('reserved_room_type', 'Raumtyp',  c('A','D','E','F','G')),
              div(),
              selectInput('deposit_type', 'Deposit-Typ', c('No deposit','Non Refund','Refundable')),
              div(),
              selectInput('customer_type', 'Kundentyp', c('Transient','Transient-Party','Contract','Group')),
              div(),
              sliderInput('adr','Kosten', min = 0, max = 1000, value = 0))),
        
        box(title = 'Numerical variables',
            status = 'primary', width = 12,
            splitLayout(
              cellWidths = c('22%', '4%','21%', '4%', '21%', '4%', '21%'),
              sliderInput('total_of_special_requests', 'Sonderwuensche',  min = 0, max = 5, value = 0),
              div(),
              sliderInput('previous_bookings_not_canceled', 'Buchungen_nicht_storniert',  min = 0, max = 3, value = 0)),
        
        box(
          title = 'Prediction result',
          width = 12, 
          height = 260,
          textOutput('predicted_value'),
          actionButton('cal', 'Calculate', icon = icon('calculator'))
        )
      )
    )
  )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      hotel = input$hotel,
      adults = input$adults,
      children = input$children,
      babies = input$babies,
      meal = input$meal,
      is_repeated_guest = input$is_repeated_guest,
      previous_cancellations = input$previous_cancellations,
      previous_bookings_not_cancelled = input$previous_bookings_not_canceled,
      reserved_room_type = input$reserved_room_type,
      deposit_type = input$deposit_type,
      customer_type = input$customer_type,
      adr = input$adr,
      total_of_special_requests = input$total_of_special_requests)
    
    
    # Create your dataset here
    
  })
  
  output$predicted_value <- renderText({
    
    predict(model_rf, data(), type = "prob")
    
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(input$cal)
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)```
````

Comment: Thanks again for your help. The error doesn't no longer appears. But unfortunately another error is shown which I am not able to fix because when comparing train_x and hotel all variables are shown equally: Error in predict.randomForest: variables in the training data missing in newdata. Could you look again where the error could be in the code and what I have to do to make it work? Below you can see the current code.

Answer (score -1):

````
  list(
    hotel = c(
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "City Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "City Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "City Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", 
      "Resort Hotel", "Resort Hotel", "City Hotel"), 
    is_canceled = c(0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
                    0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    adults = c(2, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
               2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 
               2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 3, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), 
    children = c(0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
                 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    babies = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
               0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), 
    meal = c("BB", 
             "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "FB", "BB", "HB", "BB", "HB", 
             "BB", "HB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "SC", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", 
             "BB", "HB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "SC", "BB", "BB", "BB", 
             "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "HB", "BB", "BB", "BB", "Undefined", "Undefined", 
             "BB", "FB", "BB", "FB", "HB"), 
    is_repeated_guest = c(
      0, 0, 0, 
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 1
    ), 
    previous_cancellations = c(
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0
    ), 
    previous_bookings_not_canceled = c(
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
      0
    ), 
    reserved_room_type = c(
      "C", "C", "A", "A", "A", "A", "C", 
      "C", "A", "D", "E", "D", "D", "G", "E", "D", "E", "A", "A", "G", 
      "F", "A", "A", "D", "D", "D", "D", "E", "A", "D", "A", "D", "E", 
      "A", "D", "D", "A", "D", "D", "E", "G", "D", "F", "E", "A", "G", 
      "A", "E", "A", "E"
    ), 
    deposit_type = c(
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "Refundable", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "Non Refund", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "Non Refund", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "Refundable", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "Non Refund", "No Deposit", "Non Refund", 
      "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", "No Deposit", 
      "Refundable", "No Deposit", "No Deposit"
    ), 
    customer_type = c(
      "Transient", 
      "Group", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Group", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Contract", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient", "Transient-Party", "Contract", "Transient", 
      "Contract", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Contract", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", "Transient", 
      "Transient", "Transient-Party", "Contract", "Transient"
    ), 
    adr = c(
      0, 
      0, 75, 75, 98, 98, 107, 103, 82, 105, 123, 145, 97, 154, 94, 
      97, 97, 88, 107, 153, 97, 84, 84, 99, 94, 63, 79, 107, 94, 87, 
      62, 63, 108, 65, 108, 108, 98, 108, 108, 137, 117, 79, 123, 137, 
      110, 153, 58, 82, 82, 119
    ), 
    total_of_special_requests = c(
      0, 
      0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 
      1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
      1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1
    )
  ), 
  row.names = c(NA, -50L), 
  class = c("tbl_df", 
            "tbl", "data.frame")
)

hotel$is_canceled <- as.factor(hotel$is_canceled)
hotel$is_repeated_guest <- as.factor(hotel$is_repeated_guest)
hotel$meal <- as.factor(hotel$meal)
hotel$reserved_room_type <- as.factor(hotel$reserved_room_type)
hotel$deposit_type <- as.factor(hotel$deposit_type)
hotel$customer_type <- as.factor(hotel$customer_type)
hotel$adr <- as.integer(hotel$adr)
hotel$hotel <- as.factor(hotel$hotel)

library(dplyr)

train_x <- select(hotel, -is_canceled)
train_y <- hotel$is_canceled

set.seed(42)
model_rf <- randomForest::randomForest(train_x, train_y, ntree = 100)


str(train_x)
hotel <- select(hotel, -is_canceled)


library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(
    title = "Hotel Prediction",
    titleWidth = 290
  ),
  dashboardSidebar(
    width = 290,
    sidebarMenu(menuItem("Prediction", tabName = 'pred'))),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        'pred',
        # Box to display the prediction results
        
        box(
            status = 'primary', width = 12, 
            splitLayout(
              tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".shiny-split-layout > div {overflow: visible;}"))),
              cellWidths = c('0%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '19%', '4%', '8%'),
              selectInput('hotel', 'hotel', c('City Hotel','Resort Hotel')),
              div(),
              sliderInput('adults', 'Erwachsene', min = 0, max = 26, value = 0),
              div(),
              sliderInput('children', 'Kinder', min = 0, max = 3, value = 0))),
        
        
        #Filters for numeric variables
        box(
            status = 'primary', width = 12,
            splitLayout(
              cellWidths = c('22%', '4%','21%', '4%', '21%', '4%', '21%'),
              sliderInput('babies', 'Babys', min = 0, max = 10, value = 0),
              div(),
              selectInput('meal', 'Mahlzeit', c('BB','HB','SC','Undefined','FB')),
              div(),
              selectInput('is_repeated_guest', 'Wiederholter Gast',  c('1','0')),
              div(),
              sliderInput('previous_cancellations', 'Stornierungen', min = 0, max = 26, value = 0))),
        
        box(
            status = 'primary', width = 12,
            splitLayout(
              cellWidths = c('22%', '4%','21%', '4%', '21%', '4%', '21%'),
              selectInput('reserved_room_type', 'Raumtyp',  c('A','D','E','F','G')),
              div(),
              selectInput('deposit_type', 'Deposit-Typ', c('No deposit','Non Refund','Refundable')),
              div(),
              selectInput('customer_type', 'Kundentyp', c('Transient','Transient-Party','Contract','Group')),
              div(),
              sliderInput('adr','Kosten', min = 0, max = 1000, value = 0))),
        
        box(title = 'Numerical variables',
            status = 'primary', width = 12,
            splitLayout(
              cellWidths = c('22%', '4%','21%', '4%', '21%', '4%', '21%'),
              sliderInput('total_of_special_requests', 'Sonderwuensche',  min = 0, max = 5, value = 0),
              div(),
              sliderInput('previous_bookings_not_canceled', 'Buchungen_nicht_storniert',  min = 0, max = 3, value = 0)),
        
        box(
          title = 'Prediction result',
          width = 12, 
          height = 260,
          textOutput('predicted_value'),
          actionButton('cal', 'Calculate', icon = icon('calculator'))
        )
      )
    )
  )
))


server <- shinyServer(function(input, output){
  
  data <- reactive({
    data.frame(
      hotel = input$hotel,
      adults = input$adults,
      children = input$children,
      babies = input$babies,
      meal = input$meal,
      is_repeated_guest = input$is_repeated_guest,
      previous_cancellations = input$previous_cancellations,
      previous_bookings_not_cancelled = input$previous_bookings_not_canceled,
      reserved_room_type = input$reserved_room_type,
      deposit_type = input$deposit_type,
      customer_type = input$customer_type,
      adr = input$adr,
      total_of_special_requests = input$total_of_special_requests)
    
    
    # Create your dataset here
    
  })
  
  output$predicted_value <- renderText({
    
    predict(model_rf, data(), type = "prob")
    
  }) %>% 
    bindEvent(input$cal)
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)```
````

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).